# Implement message loop to catch all process messages

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm trying to implement a message loop in a control that I can use to peek at all messages in the current process, look for a specific message, and fire an event when a certain message is detected.

This is my current code:

```
    public void MessageHandler()
    {
        MSG msg;

        while (GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            if (msg.message == 272)
            {
                // Fire event here
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);
```

This loop is currently being run asynchronously. The issue I'm having is it doesn't seem that I am receiving any messages. The loop exits on the GetMessage() call.

I attempted to run the loop while(true) and continue if the return value from GetMessage() <= 0, but that seemed to produce the same result.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Message queues are per-thread, not per-process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why don't you override WndProc method. It is where you can capture almost every message passed to your window

Comment: The issue is the message is passed to a native parent window that I cannot access, otherwise WndProc would be perfect...

Comment: @HerrJoebob Hmm.. then how am I supposed to snoop on main thread messages without hanging it? I think this may be the key part i don't understand about creating a message loop.

Comment: You could use a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook if C# supports such things.

Comment: Not sure if I'm interpreting correctly.  I've successfully used [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) in the past to receive all messages intended for my application before they are dispatched to specific windows/controls.